# getting class cast exception in the below piece of code

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have this below method which purpose is to remove duplicates below is the methods shown, this method recieve a list of string type as a parameter

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

     private List<String> removeDuplicates(List keys) {

            if (isDebugEnabled)            
            Set set = new HashSet<String>();
            set.addAll(keys);
            if (set.size() < keys.size()) {
                keys.clear();
                keys.addAll(set);
            }
            return keys;
        }
```

Now the problem is that upon execution this line the exception is coming on line  `return keys;`

and the exception that is coming is

```
ERROR: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

now please advise how can i overcome from this classcast exception

Comment: at which line? anyway, as far as I can see: your keys variable can have any type, so when you try to cast it to a list of Strings, that might cause trouble

Comment: the exception is coming n the line in which i am returning the kes that is return Keys

Comment: Thanks for the advise request you to please correct my above piece of code so that i can grasp a bit more that are you are trying to explain please

Comment: what is the type of list `key`?

Comment: it is of string type as shown above

Comment: did you tried to compile it now?

Comment: @dgfdhgfhg for the compiler, it's a List of objects, not Strings. try it as List<String> keys and see what happens